# How Do I Multiply The Price And Amount?

Tags: javascript, php

How to multiply the price with the amount and display the result.This is the code i want to multiply the selected price with the selected amount and display the result:

```
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Order</title>
<link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="buttons.css">
</head>

<body>

$_SESSION['link'] = $_POST['link'];
echo '<img src="'.$_SESSION['link'] .'">'; 
?>

Order

<form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
ProductID: <input type="text" name="ProductID" id="ProductID">
Color: <input type="text" name="Color" id="Color">
Amount: <input type="number" name="Amount" id="Amount">
Price: echo ''.$_SESSION['price'].'';
?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button">

</form> 

<script>
```

Comment: where is your price textbox ?

Comment: The price is from php database

Comment: you storing your data in `SESSIONS` ?

Comment: and where is the amount data ?

Comment: That what im trying to solve to get  the total price based on the amount entered for the item

Answer (score 1):

[Demo on JS Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/7namuehs/2/)

HTML + PHP:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="register-form" novalidate="novalidate">
    ProductID: <input type="text" name="ProductID" id="ProductID"/>
    Color: <input type="text" name="Color" id="Color"/>
    Amount: <input type="number" name="Amount" id="Amount"/>
    Price: <span id="price"><?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?></span>
    <br/>
    Result: <span id="result"></span>
```

JS:

```
$('#Amount').keyup(function() {
   var price = parseFloat($('#price').text());
   $('#result').text(price * parseFloat($(this).val()));
});
```

Comment: Hi Sir the result is still not displayed

Comment: I've changed `change` event to `keyup` event, now, every time you type anything to `Amount` field, it should be multiplied and displayed in `span#result`, of course, if you've wrapped price in `span#price`.

Comment: Are you sure your HTML code looks exactly like in my answer and JavaScript code is wrapped in `<script>` tags, declared after jQuery lib?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<input type="text" name="Price" id="Price" <?php echo ''.$_SESSION['price'].''; ?>>
```

and use form's attribute  **onSubmit** multiply using javascript or using **action** on given page `$result = $_POST['Price'] * $_POST['Amount'];`